# Using a MakeFile in iOS

Tags: macos, makefile, jpcap

People, be patient with me, please...

I download Jpcap source build for Mac OS X from here: http://netresearch.ics.uci.edu/kfujii/Jpcap/doc/download.html

Then, I'm following the tutorial for installing it (for Mac OS X) from here: http://netresearch.ics.uci.edu/kfujii/Jpcap/doc/install.html

It says:
4. Go to '[Jpcap extracted directory]/src/c' directory. 
5. Run 'make'.

When I go to `/src/c`, I see a file named "Makefile", without an extension. What should I do with it?

PS: I already have Xcode installed in my machine.

Please, tell me in details, cause I don't have much experience in iOS, and my main language is not English.
Thanks!

Comment: The [tag wiki for "make"](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/make/info) might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You are seeing what is expected: just a file called **Makefile**.

`make` is an executable which will read any `Makefile` in the current directory.

So, just run `make`.

I think it might be easier to use a packaging system like macports, Fink or Homebrew to build these sort of things, as someone else will have done the packaging of the builds for you.

(Also, btw, it is not 'MACOS', but Mac OS X.)